# Compiling old latex files - is it possible to go back in time?

Tags: compiling

I am trying to compile LaTeX sources from 10 years ago. Surprisingly, it doesn't succeed. Assuming it once did, I believe the problem is with updated packages that now collide, etc.

Is it possible to somehow get a platform with "LaTeX from 10 years ago" containing all the correct versions?

Thanks

Comment: Sure: ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/  (for example) -- dates back to 1996.

Comment: Is there a way to run one of these in a 'sandbox' environment, without overriding or otherwise corrupting my current latex environment?

Comment: Generally, you can have as many editions of TeX Live installed as you wish if you are using upstream's vanilla version.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what's a vanilla version. Is it something I can use on Windows/mac?

Answer (score 3):

TeX Live has a historical archive going back to 1996: ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/. It's quite possible to install several different TeX systems at the same time and swap between them using the path. (I for example have TeX Live 2009-2015 inclusive on my laptop for testing.) However, it's hard to predict if you might need one or more 'intermediate' files to help: these snap shots are after all spaced out by an entire year each.